# installing multiple servers

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm beginner in SQL. Recently I installed Wamp and Xampp servers on my laptop and I faced with some errors in Apache.  So I deleted Xampp on my laptop and now I using Wamp server. Now I'm studying MySQL in phpmyadmin  in Wamp server. Also I want to learn SQL server.
If I install SQL server on my laptop, is it compatible with phpmyadmin or I must delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Installing SQL server on your laptop has nothing to do with your existing installation/set up of WAMP. You dont need to delete phymyadmin or even worry about the compatiblity as mysql and SQL server are different products.